# Подскажите правильный паттерн для рефакторинга

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Всем привет, я понимаю, что вопрос у меня не очень конкретный, но я постараюсь по возможности его превратить в несколько маленьких вопросов.
Мне достался великолепный legasy код службы, который писался более 15 лет назад (Windows, c++ 03). Этот сервис реализует подсчет контрольных сумм для файлов/значений реестра. Для взаимодействия с сервисом реализован RPC сервер, для соединения с которым есть dll библиотека, и сделана возможность обрабатывать сообщения от другого сервиса (тоже по RPC, но уже являясь клиентом). Т.е. есть два источника команд, так же есть планировщик, который может выполнять проверку контрольных сумм по расписанию.
На текущий момент вся реализация сделана через классы, предоставляющие наборы функций (буду называть их функциональные классы) - например, класс контрольных сумм не хранит состояний, но имеет методы посчитать, сравнить и т.д. Так же есть классы, которые реализуют работу с конкретным объектом для контрольной суммы - т.е. получить содержимое, получить атрибуты.

Как это работает сейчас - по очереди создаются все функциональные классы начиная от тех, которые ни от кого не зависят и заканчивая самыми требовательными. и получается, что созданный один раз экземпляр класса подсчета контрольных сумм тащится во все места сервиса. И получается, что какой нибудь класс C содержит в себе указатели на классы A и B, и требует на них указатели в конструкторе. И так же класс B содержит указатель на класс A и имеет параметр конструктора. И все они переплетены в большой клубок, где бывает до 6 параметров.

Я прекрасно понимаю, что поменять всю архитектуру целиком мне не удастся, это потребует много ресурсов и времени, но я хочу по возможности ее причесать. Я не смог найти ни одного паттерна, к которому можно привязать подобный стиль разработки, и потому первый вопрос - к какому паттерну это можно привести?

Второй вопрос - если классы реализуют только функции, то их экземпляры можно создать во всех классах, где они используются, но не приведет ли это к падению производительности(почти каждый класс грузит dll библиотеку с нужным ему функционалом)? Как ужасный вариант вижу, что то что есть сейчас можно свести к огромному числу Singleton, но это создаст огромное число скрытых зависимостей.

Так же есть вопрос по логированию - для него так же существует объект, который реализует запись в лог, и многие другие классы его дергают, как лучше поступить с ним? Так же передавать через параметр конструктора или сделать Singleton и вызывать где надо?

Comment: если класс реализует только функции, то может и класс не нужен? а просто функции в namespace или сделать их статическими.

Comment: [вряд ли что-то хорошее тут придумаешь](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/OO_programming/)

Comment: О таких вариантах я тоже думал, но там есть не много полиморфизма и одна маленькая фабрика

Comment: по поводу конструирования объектов - по описанию похоже на то, что подойдет использование `прототипа`. Что касается "функциональных классов" - это абсолютно нормальная вещь - подозреваю, что они храняться все вместе в каком-нибудь пуле и вызываются через интерфейс базового абстрактного класса. Что касается логирования - запись логов необходимо осуществлять через макросы, так вы сможете не заморачиваясь менять способ форматирования и записи логов, или вообще их убрать. Объект же для сбора логов следует настроить как можно раньше, в идеале прямо в main, чтобы запись логов стала доступна сразу.

Comment: Заявления что "классы не хранят состояния" и что "там есть не много полиморфизма" и "почти каждый класс грузит dll библиотеку" противоречат друг другу. И вообще непонятно, чего вы хотите добиться и почему. Оно что, неправильно работает? "я хочу по возможности ее причесать" недостаточная причина для изменений

Comment: На сколько я понял, вам нужен патерн   "Актер"

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, на текущий момент используется в качестве логгирования передача сообщений другой службе, для это в самом начале создается объект, указатель на который передается во все классы, которые могут что-то важное передать. Вот при такой реализации этот объект лучше завернуть в Singleton или так же и держать параметром?

Comment: @user7860670, Например, есть dll работы с базой данных одного типа и другого типа, есть интерфейс и написаны два класса, которые интерфейс поддерживают, и соответственно уровнем выше уже все равно какая база. Или для ключей и ресурсов набор действий один, а класс который будет его осуществлять определяется фабрикой. Она выдает указатель на класс, в котором содержится набор функций для обработки данного типа. Сейчас у меня есть программа, которая все время достраивалась за счет костылей и время. Я хочу костыли убрать, что бы когда меня попросили что-то сделать, не было бы побочных эффектов

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, Плохо гуглится, это [оно](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model)?

Comment: *"Например, есть dll работы с базой данных одного типа и другого типа, есть интерфейс и написаны два класса, которые интерфейс поддерживают, и соответственно уровнем выше уже все равно какая база. Или для ключей и ресурсов набор действий один, а класс который будет его осуществлять определяется фабрикой. Она выдает указатель на класс, в котором содержится набор функций для обработки данного типа."* - так а что вас тут не устраивает?

Comment: @drem1lin, да, этот.  И еще https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns

Comment: @user7860670 Те классы которые я привел - самые простые, но они создаются один раз и дальше передаются в другие классы. Но вот нужно ли это? или можно везде создавать свой экземпляр таких функциональных классов?

Comment: Да, вроде вполне нормальная практика. Зависимости получаются изолированы, и подгружаются только один раз. Загрузка dll - дело же не дешевое. Конечно вместо явной передачи можно нагородить какого-нибуть внедрения зависимостей, но выгода от нагромождения дополнительного кода будет сомнительной.